# Simple MIPS Assembly program that gets user input and stores it

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to write a function that asks the user for two numbers, one at a time. The first one goes well, however I'm having trouble with the second (I've duplicated the lines, "ask" is a string asking the user to add an input). What is wrong?

```
main:
    addi    $sp, $29, -8
    sw  $31, 0($29) # save register 31 (ra)  (since there is a nested / recursive procedure)

    sw  $0, 4($29)  # Space for parameter n1 on stack
    li  $v0, 4      # Ask for number
    la  $a0, ask    
    syscall
    li  $v0, 5      # read int
    syscall         # $v0 holds the integer - n1
    sw  $v0, 4($29) # save n1 on stack
    move    $a0, $v0    # prepare argument for func




    sw  $0, 4($29)  # Space for parameter n2 on stack
    li  $v1, 4      # Ask for number
    la  $a1, ask    
    syscall
    li  $v1, 5      # read int
    syscall         # $v1 holds the integer - n2
    sw  $v1, 4($29) # save n2 on stack
    move    $a1, $v1    # prepare argument for func
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
sw  $0, 4($29)  # Space for parameter n2 on stack
```

you overwrite the n1 in stack.

You have only reserved room for one parameter and return address in the stack.

Also the syscalls use certain registers for certain data. You can't decide:

```
li  $v1, 4      # Ask for number
la  $a1, ask    
syscall
```